# EOF when using cpickle to serialize an object

Tags: python, pickle

I have the following quote which seems to work fine:

```
from cPickle import *
class Clientthread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self,clientsocket, mystring):
      self.client = clientsocket
      self.clients = [clientsocket]
      self.testEntity = entity.Entity(position = [1,7])
      self.testTosend = dumps(self.testEntity,2)
      self.client.send(self.testTosend)
```

However, when I try to deserialize the whole stuff with

```
 news=self.s.recv(1024)
 realnews = loads(news)
```

I get an EOF-error in the line that uses loads.
Any idea where that could be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

assuming `self.s` is a `socket`. The `recv` method does not always return the exact amount of bytes as you request. As noted in the [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) documentation the amount is the **maximum** amount of bytes to be returned by `recv`.

This causes incomplete data to be passed to your `loads`.

Comment: Oh.Well that explains a lot.

Comment: Any idea how I can find out how many bytes my object had? If it should be to big, is there another method to receive all the bytes? And yes, s is, of course, a socket.

Comment: You need to setup some kind of protocol to send things over sockets. The simplest method would be sending each block of _data_ with the size in bytes in front of it. That way the receiving end always knows how much bytes to expect and read.

Comment: Well I did check - in fact I am sending 191 bytes - so there is no way that the object is to big. Is there any other possible cause for the bug?

Comment: Or, to put differently, the receiving end may receive 4096 bytes, but I am only sending 191. What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Try replacing the `self.client.send` with `self.client.sendall`. You also might want to reread the socket documentation.